# Annotating the last value for any/all matplotlib graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

**Question** I am creating a compilation of around 120 graphs into an economic booklet. While I have successfully completed it, **I would like to annotate the last value of my graphs** (regardless of type such as line, horizontal bar, vertical bar, stacked bar, line & bar, etc).

**Background:** While searching for a solution on Stack Overflow, I found similar questions, however, I found it difficult to apply to my exact situation. I believe this is because when I originally created my graph compilation it was very inefficient. Currently, my booklet is a total of 3485 lines of code, which I believe is way too much. As such, if suggestions/recommendations/examples could be provided to clean up the code provided for one of my graphs so I can apply it to all of them it would be greatly appreciated.

**Current Processes & Concerns:** I have made slight changes to my original code to allow easy replicability and testing. Major concerns I have regarding my code and the thinking process I used is as follows:

1. My Dates are string values (e.g. 2021M1, 2021Q1, 2021). I tried using Date values however, creating dynamic x-ticks/labels and graph formatting kept messing up. Not all graphs start on the same date or end on the same date where having static x-ticks will result in different spacing between x-tick labels. Ideally, I wanted to create a standard spacing/labeling for example: For the GDP graph, the data is from 2004Q1 to 2022Q2, and soon 2022Q3 will be added. Having a total of 5-6 static points such as 2004Q1 (first data point), 2008Q1, 2012Q1, 2016Q1, 2020Q1, 2022Q? (last data point). Most likely I was doing something wrong, but could not figure it out so I resorted to using string values.
2. As a result of my Dates being string values, I created a list comprehension of x-tick values using the DataFrames index and of x-tick labels.
3. Since I am creating a compilation of matplotlib graphs and outputting it as a PDF file, I am using one fig and sub plotting up to 4 graphs on each page. As such, I wanted the flexibility to change the colors of the graphs/lines, graph title, graph label. However, all the graphs have the figure size, line width, font size, text style and font, font weight, font color, padding size. I was unsure how I could efficiently organize this and just went with what worked.

**Attempts:** I have tried using `ax.annotate` and failed. I'm sure this is most likely the best solution to my case, but am unable to apply it to my situation, which is why I am requesting help from all of you.

Sorry for the long post and thank you for staying with me so far. I appreciate any and all guidance.

**Expected Output (Graph):**
[image]

**Replicated Output (Graph):**

[image]

**Replicated Output (Table):**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Nov 14 10:19:21 2022

@author: sodbileg.g
"""

#Import modules/packages
import sys
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from textwrap import wrap
import math
from pathlib import Path
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

#Random PATH for sample
PATH2 = r"D:\\"

#Excel Data as New DataFrames (created sample one for easy copying and testing)
data = {"Date": ["2021Q2", "2021Q3", "2021Q4", "2022Q1", "2022Q2"],
        "World": [4.40, 5.90, 5.50, 4.10, 3.60],
        "Major Trading Partenrs GDP Growth": [7.93, 4.89, 4.01, 4.78, 0.34],
        "China GDP Growth": [7.90, 4.90, 4.00, 4.80, 0.40],
        "Euro Area GDP Growth": [14.60, 3.90, 4.80, 5.40, 3.90],
        "Japan GDP Growth": [7.30, 1.20, 0.50, 0.70, 1.10],
        "U.S. GDP Growth": [12.20, 4.90, 5.50, 3.50, 1.60]
        }

#Read-In Excel Data as New DataFrames
df001_A = pd.DataFrame(data)
df001_A.columns = ('Date','world_g', 'majortr_g','china_g','euro_g','japan_g','us_g')

#Create a List Comp of X-Ticks
date_list_A = df001_A["Date"].dropna().to_list()
list_len_A = len(date_list_A)-1
div_int_A = math.floor(((list_len_A))/4)
list_comp_A = [x for x in range(len(df001_A.index)) if x % div_int_A == 0]
list_comp_A[4] = list_len_A

#Create a List Comp of X-Tick-Labels
div_int_A2 = (list_len_A-(div_int_A*4))
label001_A = date_list_A[0]
label002_A = date_list_A[0+(div_int_A)]
label003_A = date_list_A[0+(div_int_A)*2]
label004_A = date_list_A[0+(div_int_A)*3]
label005_A = date_list_A[(0+(div_int_A)*4)+div_int_A2]

#Create PDF File (Page 1)
with PdfPages(PATH2+'01.pdf') as export_pdf:        
    plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"
    plt.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':4},frameon=False)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.20, hspace=0.5) 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=False, sharey=False, squeeze=True)
    
    #Plot Graph 1.1                     
    df001_A.plot(kind='line', x='Date', y='world_g', linewidth=0.7,figsize=(8,6), color='mediumblue',fontsize=4,label="World", ax=ax[0,0])
    df001_A.plot(kind='line', x='Date', y='majortr_g', linewidth=0.7,figsize=(8,6), color='orange',fontsize=4,label="Major trading partners (China, Russia)", ax=ax[0,0])

    ax[0,0].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
    ax[0,0].set_xticks([list_comp_A[0], list_comp_A[1], list_comp_A[2], list_comp_A[3], list_comp_A[4]], minor=False)
    ax[0,0].set_xlabel("")
    ax[0,0].set_xticklabels([label001_A, label002_A, label003_A, label004_A, label005_A],rotation=0)
    ax[0,0].set_title(label='GDP growth-World (%, YoY)',fontweight=8, pad='2.0',fontsize=5, style='italic')
    plt.suptitle('1.World Economy',fontweight='bold',fontsize=12, color='black')
    
    #Graph Tick Paramters
    ax[0,0].tick_params(axis="y", which="major", labelleft = True, labelright = True, pad=1.5, width=0.4, labelsize=4)
    ax[0,0].yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
    
    export_pdf.savefig(orientation = 'landscape')
    plt.close()
```